# Visual Studio and image fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi im trying to run this code: [Img Fade](https://codepen.io/ChristosX/pen/NyjyrG)

to my visual studio but doesnt work!

my libraries is this:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Missing something on library?

Comment: Seems all fine...

Comment: PS, why don't you use CSS, `:hover`, `opacity` and `transition` ? (No JS needed)

Comment: Here's a CSS example: https://jsfiddle.net/aoojbyg3/

Comment: Thank you very much that works!